# Link covered by image-wrap

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The links on the images are being hidden or covered and I cannot figure out why. The first `<a href..` below is an example of this.. Live version can be found [here](http://fundraisingfountain.pixelworklab.com/product-category/pillow-pets/).. Basically any of the product images should be clickable..

```
<div class="image-wrap">
    <a href="http://fundraisingfountain.pixelworklab.com/product/bull-dog/" title="Bull Dog">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="http://fundraisingfountain.pixelworklab.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Pillow-Pets-Bulldog-2-150x150.png" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="Pillow Pets - Bulldog (2)">         
    </a>

    <ul class="product-details">
        <li class="details">
            <a class="button details" href="http://fundraisingfountain.pixelworklab.com/product/bull-dog/" title="Bull Dog">View Details</a>
        </li>
        <li class="price-wrap">
            <a href="http://fundraisingfountain.pixelworklab.com/product/bull-dog/" title="Bull Dog"><span class="price"><strong><span class="amount">$25</span></strong></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="cart">
            <a href="/product-category/pillow-pets/?add-to-cart=164" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="164" data-product_sku="003" class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple">Add to cart</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my machine.

You'll have to check your CSS and make sure that there are no div tags that are layered on top of it (or have a higher z-index than it).

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have set `ul` `height:100%` that is why it overlaps the image.

Change the `height` for the `ul` to something smaller and it will work fine

`woocommerce.css Line # 634`

```
ul.products li.product .product-details{
     height:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

btw if you give a

```
 border="0"
```

to your image links there wil be no grey (or any other color) border around it

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to fix

```
ul.products li.product .product-details {
    height: auto;
    top: 108%;
}

ul.products li.product .product-details li {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```